# Restoring default PATH in windows8

Tags: windows, powershell, path

I recently changed the default PATH in windows8,so how do I change it back?

I tried using this PATH -> `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

But it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$newPath = '%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\'
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $newPath, 'Machine')
```

If you start a new PowerShell instance after running the above, you should see the new values for PATH.